# How to shorten timeout in WCF client

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-client

How to make timeout in WCF client shorter. I want to call some WCF service periodically and check if it is available or not. I want that call to the service method be no longer than one second. I am trying to manipulate different timeouts but in each case it is executing for more than 20 seconds.

Below you'll find my code:

Service:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ICustomerManager
{
    [OperationContract]
    void StoreCustomer(string customerName);

    [OperationContract]
    void Ping();
}
[ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true)]    
public class CustomerManager : MarshalByRefObject, ICustomerManager
{
    public void StoreCustomer(string customerName)
    {
        if(customerName == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("customerName");
        Console.WriteLine(customerName + " stored.");
    }

    public void Ping()
    { 
    }
}
```

Client:

```
var binding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None);
binding.OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
binding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
binding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
binding.CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
binding.ReliableSession.Enabled = true;
var bindingElements = binding.CreateBindingElements();
var tcpBindingElement = bindingElements.Find<TcpTransportBindingElement>();
tcpBindingElement.ChannelInitializationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);            

var factory = new ChannelFactory<ICustomerManager>(binding, "net.tcp://10.68.117.19:9998/CustomerManager");
var customerManager = factory.CreateChannel();
var contextChannel = customerManager as IClientChannel;

contextChannel.OperationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);

var start = DateTime.Now;
 try
 {
     customerManager.Ping();
 }
 catch (CommunicationException)
 {
     var elapsed = DateTime.Now - start;
     Console.WriteLine("elapsed: {0}", elapsed);
 }
```

The output is:  `elapsed: 00:00:20.8662525`

How to make it to execute no longer than a second.

I am not attaching code for my server because I am testing a case when it is not available.

I have found very similar problem on msdn forum [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/80f576b8-9d6d-4043-a1a2-8decb8e165a6) unfortunately answer there also does not work.